# filtering specific DIVs based on their contents

Tags: javascript

I have tried the below, I want to entirely hide the card, if it does not contain the search text, but it doesn't work - can anyone help me please :)

Form:

```
              <input class="form-control" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Enter a search term (e.g. Python)">
```

Example cards are as below. I want to say, if anywhere in the card content, the word in the search box exists, keep that card showing

```
<div class="card mb-2 itemstodo" id="filterme">
   <div class="row g-0 sh-10">
      <div class="col-2 h-100" style="padding: 15px 15px;">
         <img src="/static/py.png" width="50px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-7">
         <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column pt-0 pb-0 h-100 justify-content-center">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
               <div> 
                  <font size="3"> <a onclick="rep('<iframe src=&quot;https://streamable.com/e/ym4kxl&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; height=&quot;100%&quot; allowfullscreen style=&quot;width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;&quot;></iframe>')">The theory of variables in Python</a></font>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1">
         <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column pt-0 pb-0 h-100 justify-content-center">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
               <div>
                  <form action="/editplan/" name="form3" ,="" id="form3" method="post">
                     <input type="hidden" n>
                     <button class="btn btn btn-icon btn-icon-only btn-outline-primary mb-1" type="submit" value="9zUGRI7qMwnKPVxDoGqS0TcALT4xpHtBlaCWV" name="editbut">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="cs-icon cs-icon-check">
                           <path d="M16 5L7.7051 14.2166C7.32183 14.6424 6.65982 14.6598 6.2547 14.2547L3 11"></path>
                        </svg>
                     </button>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The JS I tried is;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#filterme").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
```